# Transform oData output

Tags: c#, odata

What I would like to do is have an oData C# service that calls a sproc that get's all the data needed.  There are really two parts of the data I want to normalize in the output but is given to me in one result set.  Is there a way to manipulate the output to place unique sets of data in the result into collections in the output.  Such that:

retrieved data (from db query):

```
Data: [{Name:"",Date:"",Age:"",Address:"",City:"",State:""},...]
```

outputed data (to client):

```
Data: [{Name,"",Date:"",Age:"",Locations:[{Address:"",City:"",State:""},...]}...]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you're mapping an OData query to your sproc, but I'll operate under the assumption that it's something like OData Endpoints for ASP.NET Web API.

You could try returning a group-by projection as the `IQueryable` for your endpoint.  Something like:

```
DbQuery().GroupBy(x => new {x.Name, x.Date, x.Age})
         .Select(g => new 
          {
              g.Key.Name, 
              g.Key.Date,
              g.Key.Age, 
              Locations = g.Select(x => new {x.Address, x.City, x.State})
          });
```